# Cpanel phpMyAdmin Internal Server Error 500

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

I installed Cpanel on Rocky 9 on EC2 instance. When I try to access the phpMyAdmin from WHM or user cpanel I get this error 500 internal server error.

I'm using the ip of the server to access the cpanel currently (no SSL).

Example: server ip is 1.1.1.1, I visit 1.1.1.1:2087 to login to WHM. When I go to phpMyAdmin I get this error the link becomes: `https://1-1-1-1.cprapid.com:2087/cpsess7237697460/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/index.php`

I checked `/usr/local/cpanel/logs/error_log` and found this:

```
==> cpsrvd 11.112.0.3 started
==> cpsrvd: loading security policy....Done
==> cpsrvd: Setting up SSL support ... Done
==> cpsrvd: transferred port bindings: 10,11,12,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
==> cpsrvd: bound to ports
[2023-06-24 16:40:57 +0000] info [cpsrvd] version 11.112.0.3 online
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/81/bin/php-cgi: error while loading shared libraries: libldap_r-2.4.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[2023-06-24 16:40:58 +0000] warn [whostmgrd] The subprocess (php) exited with an error (ID 595246399826468): The subprocess reported error number 127 when it ended.
[2023-06-24 16:40:58 +0000] info [whostmgrd] Internal Server Error: "GET /cpsess8864581121/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Error (ID 595246399826468)
```

Not sure if this is the reason.

I tried to update cpanel `/scripts/upcp --force` and:

1- Repair cPanel's Internal RPMs.
`/scripts/check_cpanel_pkgs --fix`

2- Restart the cPanel service daemon.
`/scripts/restartsrv_cpsrvd --hard`

I tried to use other versions of PHP.

All tries didn't work and I still get the same error.

**Update:** Roundcube for mail is not working either https://1-1-1-1.cprapid.com:2087/cpsess7237697460/3rdparty/roundcube/index.php.

I tried to update this file `/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/index.php`
but it's just showing the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this issue on an AlmaLinux 9.3 machine. I found an issue with the cPanel FPM service.

```
systemctl status cpanel_php_fpm.service
```

If that is failed you will also see that libldap_r-2.4.so.2 is missing. After a yum search found the correct package.

```
yum search libldap
```

Then installed the correct package (x86_64 in my case)

```
yum install openldap-compat.x86_64
```

Hope it helps!